# Reading a value from cell and searching for that value it in the different Excel cells

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote this function that **takes a value of one cell and looks for it in another cell** (in a different sheet):

```
Sub FindJobnRow() 
Dim TempTargetRow As Variant

TargetRow = vbNullString
JobNo = vbNullString
JobNo = Worksheets("Working").Range("B1:B1").Value
MsgBox (JobNo)

Set TempTargetRow = Worksheets("Planas").Range("C:C").Find(what:=**JobNo**, Lookat:=xlWhole)
If Not TempTargetRow Is Nothing Then
TargetRow = TempTargetRow.Row
Else
MsgBox (JobNo & "Not Found")
End If

Set TempTargetRow = Nothing
End Sub
```

Value is being read from a cell and stored in JobNo as a string (declared as program/module wide). The code won't find the value, but if I type in the value instead of variable it works:

```
Set TempTargetRow = Worksheets("Planas").Range("C:C").Find(what:=**19569**, Lookat:=xlWhole)
```

I guess it is some whitespaces problem, but `Trim()` does not seem do be helping.

Comment: Try using `.Range("B1")` instead of `.Range("B1:B1")`. Then debug your code and find out whether you variable `JobNo`  takes the value.

Comment: Ok, thnx i'll try that out, but what bothers me is that it finds the value if i hardcode it... which sort of means that the logic i'm using is correct

Comment: And other thing that I've missed - use `"*" & JobNo & "*"` instead of `**JobNo**`.

Comment: No, those * is Stackoverflow formating, ignore that. not familiar this Stackowerflow functuonality - idea was to set bold on the part i talk

Comment: When you do: `..Find(what:=19569,..` you are providing a number to look for. As you haven't declared `JobNo`, it is set as type of `Variant`.. which is NOT a number. Declare it as: `Dim JobNo As Long` and then try it. **Hint**: `Option Explicit` is your friend

Comment: Mr. Zac you are absolutley right. It works now. Thank you very much for such a swift and greate answer!!!